# Clarification on stokes theorem

Tags: surface-integrals, stokes-theorem, curl

Stokes theorem says:

$\int_C  \vec{F}$•$\vec dr$ =$\iint_\sum (\nabla \mathbf x \vec{F})•\hat n$ $d\sigma$

This means

$\int_C \vec{F}$•$\vec dr$ = $\iint_R (\nabla \mathbf x \vec{F})•\hat n$  $||\partial \vec r/du$ $\mathbf x $ $\partial \vec r/dv||$ $ dudv$.

Right?

Comment: Although you're talking about a quite famous formula, it makes sense to explain the notation. This will help you get more answers, than just stating the formula of your problem.

Comment: I will edit it but is it right or wrong?